Can we connect to Azure MySQL database from Google Data Studio
Is there a way to create a data source to Azure MySQL database in Google Data Studio?
What is the public IP of Google Data studio that I can give access to in my Azure MySQL database?
Thanks in advance!
couldnt connect to Azure MySQL database from google data studio.

Does this help - https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7088031?hl=en&ref_topic=7332343#notes&zippy=%2Cin-this-article

To connect to an Azure MySQL database in Looker Studio, follow the procedure below:

According to this add 142.251.74.0/23, i.e., start IP 142.251.74.0 and end IP 142.251.75.255, to the Azure MySQL server firewall rule as shown below:



Select the MySQL DataSource option while creating a data source in Looker Studio, enter the required database details, download the SSL certificate from the network tab of the server, check "Enable SSL," and upload the downloaded certificate to connect as shown below:



Click on "Authenticate." It will connect successfully, as shown below:


